# Synchronising a remote folder with a local one

Tags: windows-7, sync, network-shares, nas

I am using a network disk (that's connected to my router by USB) to store several data files. A simple .NET application that I've created is supposed to read and modify these data files. However, some security issues are preventing this application to access these files directly. (Actually, these have been built-in to my application *on purpose* since it's not going to support NAS disks.)

Since this disk is shared with several computers, I just want to have a simple synchronisation method, which will copy the files to a local folder where my application can access them. And, once modified, it should send back the modified files to the NAS disk again.

I have two options:

1. Build a second application to do my own synchronisation.
2. Find some build-in function inside Windows 7 Ultimate which can do this for me.

Option 2 is preferred. Option 1 is something I can do easily, if need be. I don't need third-party tools. (Still, feel free to add some references to good tools, although I won't accept them as answers.) Basically, is this possible with Windows 7 and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Windows 7 Sync Centre in Control Panel?

Comment: Yes. It's useful to synchronise my mobile phone with my computer. I don't know if it can be used to synchronise between a local folder and a remote folder on some network device. Ah, correction... I see. Good point. Trying. :-)

Comment: Ah, tested. Fount the problem. Even after using Sync Centre, the files still needs to be accessed on a network disk, even though it keeps a local copy. Since my application will detect the disk as being a network disk, it will not allow the files/folders to be accessed. If only I knew the local foldername where Sync Centre stores it's local copies. And if I could modify the files there, great!

Comment: Also found the local location of those network files. It's in C:\Users\wim\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache\Content and it's all heavily encrypted. Thus, not available locally.